# cakephp Model array index issue

Tags: arrays, cakephp, model, indexing

I have a weird problem with Model arrays 
I moved a website from a test server to a live server. 
In the new situation all my code started to complaine about undefined 
indexes. When debugging an array I saw that the array indexes became 
numbers instead of the Model names!? What can be the problem of that? I 
use the exact same installation of cakephp? 
Below the 2 examples of arrays.

### this is how the array should be.

```
Array( 
[0] => Array 
    ( 
        [MenuItemsTemplates] => Array 
            ( 
                [id] => 152 
                [menu_item_id] => 1 
            ) 
    )
)
```

### This is the array on the live server

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array 
    ( 
        [0] => Array 
            ( 
                [id] => 152 
                [menu_item_id] => 1 
            ) 
    )
```

)

Comment: Which version of CakePHP, database and PHP on both servers?

Comment: Cakephp 2 on both. And PHP Version 5.3.10, mysql 5.0.92 on the test server and PHP Version 5.2.4, mysql 4.1.21 on the live

Comment: As mentioned in the [requirements](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html#requirements) for CakePHP 2, you need PHP 5.2.8 or greater.

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP 2.x is not compatible with PHP 4. You must have PHP 5.2.8 or higher.